# In Laravel Stripe - No such price: 'false'

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

Stripe is integrated into Laravel. When I created a new subscription in Stripe. I faced the issue like

Stripe \ Exception \ InvalidRequestException

No such price: 'false'

My code is

```
    $plan = Plan::find($request->plan);
    $amount = $request->amount;
    $amount = $amount * 100;
    $paymentMethod = $request->payment_method;

    $user = auth()->user();
    $user->createOrGetStripeCustomer();
            
    if ($paymentMethod != null) {
        $paymentMethod = $user->addPaymentMethod($paymentMethod);
    }
    $paymentId = $paymentMethod->id;     
    
    
    $stripe =  $user->newSubscription(
        'default', $plan
    )->create( $paymentId);`enter code here`
```

sometimes I faced this type of error

The payment attempt failed because additional action is required before it can be completed.

Comment: For the InvalidRequestException, you are passing a boolean 'false' while you need to pass a Price id.
I invite you to follow this guide for building a complete Subscription integration :
https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=elements
It handles the cases where payments may requires additional actions too.

Comment: If this doesn't help, can you share more details about your integration?

Comment: @os4m37 Thanks, for your link. It helps me to find the solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient('sk_test_51NFuj0SHUnJwHMxFEUsvAR28qEzpJPeMepvnSFkUoMXexwa1hZHJRwqXVwCnW4L4qxcqdZ0L9HyCWKj4QVTYW0Av00xy4OFdR2');

           
        $subscription = $stripe->subscriptions->create([
            'customer' => $paymentMethod->customer,
            'items' => [[
                'price' => $plan->stripe_plan,
            ]],
            'payment_behavior' => 'default_incomplete',
            'payment_settings' => ['save_default_payment_method' => 'on_subscription'],
            'expand' => ['latest_invoice.payment_intent'],
        ]);
```